Are there missing lyrics in George Michael's 'Kissing A Fool'?
About 3 minutes into the song, George sings
...but you knew I loved you,
We could have shown them all,
Na na, na na, na na

That "Na na, na na, na na" seems so out of place with the rest of the song.
If you look at the video, George seems to have an embarrassed smile when he sings the 'Na's.
Earlier in the song, the response to "We could have shown them all" was "We should have seen love through". So these 'Nas' seem uncharacteristically out of place and weaker than the original powerful message of seeing love through.
Often in songs where there are repeated sections, you make minor changes to emphasize there has been a change, and to make that change significant but in a subtle way.
Were there lyrics that were originally in the song, that George took out for the official release? Perhaps because this was an autobiographical song?
I do not want to start a conspiracy theory or anything ... no wait, scratch that, I do.

Could it have been used ironically? And what exactly is your question, if there used to be other words instead of the "na na na"?
